# The size of primes and message in RSA

Tags: rsa

I am playing with a toy RSA source code. I have observed that keeping the size of primes p and q fixed if size message is changed then the decrypted text changes. If size of message is increased beyond certain values then i am not able to get the original plaintext after decryption. So please suggest what is the restriction on values of p ,q and message size. Means given a p and q should i choose plaintext of a particular size ? The sample source code is as below

```
# Write Python3 code here 
from decimal import Decimal


def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a % b)


p = int(input('Enter the value of p = '))
q = int(input('Enter the value of q = '))
no = int(input('Enter the value of text = '))
n = p * q
t = (p - 1) * (q - 1)

for e in range(2, t):
    if gcd(e, t) == 1:
        break

for i in range(1, 10):
    x = 1 + i * t
    if x % e == 0:
        d = int(x / e)
        break
print('pvt key= ', d)

ct = pow(no,e,n)

dt = pow(ct,d,n)

print('n = ' + str(n) + ' e = ' + str(e) + ' t = ' + str(t) + ' d = ' + str(d) + ' cipher text = ' + str(ct) + ' decrypted text = ' + str(dt))
```

Comment: The encrypted text will be different if either prime is changed. And to achieve unique decryption the rule is very simple: the plaintext must be less than p*q, and smaller still if you use a decent padding scheme.

Comment: RSA modulus size is chosen by the security requirement like min 2048-bit modulus. Next, we don't use the public key for encryption, we rather prefer hybrid encryption where the public key is used for key exchange like DHKE or RSA-KEM. Then data encrypted with a symmetric algorithm like AES with a proper mode as GCM. RSA is mostly used for signature and that requires special padding PSS. Note that the hash of the message is signed, not the message. This is part of the security since the first signature, Rabin Signature....

Comment: @KelaIaka, I want to use RSA for encrption of the key used for symmetric key encryption. For sending the encrypted key to the client i want to use RSA. A i doing wrong in this approach. Please comment